# Allow user to exit a unity web game being hosted on a Flask web app

Tags: javascript, python, flask, unity-webgl

My project is a web app for a school arcade machine that hosts Unity web games for students to play with their joystick and buttons.

My problem is that when I run the game I don't know how I can make the game exit or go back with just keys, whether its with Javascript `Event Listener` or a key command for example `Ctrl + Z` that I can key bind to a specific button on the machine.

This is my code:

This is my home route displaying all of the games in my game folder for the user to select:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    games_folder = os.path.join('static', 'games')
    game_files = [(os.path.join(games_folder, file), os.path.basename(file)) for file in os.listdir(games_folder)]
  
    return render_template('index.html', game_files=game_files)
```

This is the html displaying all of the links and how to get on the game:

```
    <div class="game-select"> 
        <ul>
            {% for game_path, game_name in game_files %}
                <li><a href="{{  game_path  }}/index.html">{{ game_name }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Some ideas I've had about this is making the game open up an `iframe` and somehow closing the `iframe` with a button,
or running the game like I am now and just having a button bound to a back button which I also don't know how to do.

I have thought about going into the games code and adding an event listener but I will have to do that with every game file which should be 100+ and future proofed.

Here is a link to all of my code so far : https://github.com/wowcivnerd/BHS-Arcade.